# C++ Set object member as reference/pointer of member of a different object?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

(I'm not sure if that title is worded correctly, as I'm still new to C++)

I have two classes, loosely represented here:

```
class SuperGroup
{
public:
    LayoutObj theLayout;
}

class SomeClass
{
public:
    LayoutObj myLayout;
    SuperGroup myGroup;
}
```

During `SomeClass`'s constructor, I want to set `myGroup.theLayout` to be pointing to `SomeClass`'s `searchLayout`. Something like this:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass()
{
    myGroup.theLayout = &myLayout;
}
```

Am I doing this correctly? Or do I need to be using a pointer? My code seems to compile okay, but when I execute it, it crashes, and I can tell its something to do with this assignment. Also, I'm not sure if its incorrectly coded, or if the SDK/API I'm using simply doesn't like it.

The reason I'm trying to reference `myLayout` with `SuperGroup` is because I have many methods in `SuperGroup` that need to use `myLayout` from `SomeClass`. I'm simply trying to avoid having the pass `myLayout` by reference into those methods every single time. Make sense? Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: [A book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will teach you much faster. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do indeed need a pointer.  Try using:

```
LayoutObj *theLayout;
```

Without a pointer, you are trying to assign a `LayoutObj` to a memory address.  This may compile, but is not the behavior you want.  Instead, you need a pointer to point to the memory address of a `LayoutObj`.

The line `myGroup.theLayout = &myLayout;` remains the same.

As always is the case with C++, be careful that `myLayout` does not go out of scope before `theLayout`.  If this happens, you have a dangling pointer.  If there is any risk of this, consider using a smart pointer of some kind, or otherwise modify your design to accommodate this.

Comment: That makes sense. Now, when I compile, anywhere that I try to do this, I get an error:   

myGroup.theLayout.whatever = something;

error C2228: left of '.whatever ' must have class/struct/union. It's like its not letting me access the members of theLayout since its a pointer...

Comment: @Jakobud: With pointers, you must use `->` instead of `.` (`ptr->foo` is equivalent to `(*ptr).foo`, you need to deference the pointer to use it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to use a pointer: `LayoutObj *theLayout`;

In reference to your last paragraph, I would consider the some alternative designs, such as:

- Requiring that the `LayoutObj` is passed into each method of `SuperGroup`, therefore decoupling the particular `LayoutObj` acted upon from the actions that can be performed, or
- Moving those methods to `SomeClass`, if they're not needed elsewhere, or
- Making them methods of `LayoutObj` itself.